# Binary search performing worse than linear

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

I'm practicing rudimentary programming skills on leetcode.com (I highly recommend it. It's great) and I ran into an interesting result.

I'm trying to find the **first** fixed point of a given array `A` with strictly ascending values.

I did this in two ways. First, a binary search / linear time hybrid

```
    start, end = 0, len(A) - 1
    while(start <= end):
        middle = (start + end) / 2
        if A[middle] == middle:
            for i in range(start, middle + 1):
                if A[i] == i:
                    return i
        elif A[middle] > middle:
            end = middle - 1
        elif A[middle] < middle:
            start = middle + 1
    return -1
```

This is simple binary search until I find a match, and then I iterate over all potential first fixed points, one after the other, until I find the first match. This is where the linear part comes in. For instance, suppose `len(A) = 1001` and `A[500] = 500` is the only fixed point, then I find it in one iteration of the binary search, but then I have to go from index 0 to 500 one after the other, looking for the first match. That's `n/2` or in other words `O(n)`

The second solution is purely binary search

```
    start, end = 0, len(A) - 1
    fixed_point = -1
    while(start <= end):
        middle = (start + end) / 2
        if A[middle] == middle:
            fixed_point = middle
            end = middle - 1
        elif A[middle] > middle:
            end = middle - 1
        elif A[middle] < middle:
            start = middle + 1
    return fixed_point
```

I expected it to be better, but it's actually worse.

The first solution beats 97% of all submissions when it comes to runtime, and has a runtime of 40 ms.

The second solution only beats 72% of all submissions and has a runtime of 48 ms.

I'm curious why this happens. Is the second solution really the better one?

Comment: Are the values of `A` (strictly) ascending?

Comment: Yes. The values of A are all strictly ascending.

Comment: What's meant by fixed point in an array here? Does it mean value == index?

Comment: A fixed point is an index i such that A[i] == i

Comment: Don't trust Leetcode's performance assessment too much :)  Quite often, the test data does not include scenarios that would be worst-cases for certain approaches. Also, when we are talking about a difference in 8ms, even two subsequent invocations of the same code could yield this difference. Do you mind trying to resubmit both solutions to see if the timing changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At if `A[middle] == middle`: the position of "any index of the fixed point is found". The first version more efficiently finds the start of the midpoint run, *assuming* that it occurs 'close to' (fsvo) the start of the linear scan: the cost of each binary loop is 'more expensive' (larger C), regardless of number of loops needed (O complexity). *For specific degenerate input, it should be possible to construct cases where the pure binary search is better: eg. size of n and distribution of input.*

For example, the degenerate case of `[0, 0, 0 ..., midpoint=1, 1, 1 ...]` would be be `O(n)` in the first version as the linear loop would be over `start=0..midpoint=n/2`<sup>1</sup>. **Using this degenerate data, and a large enough value of n, the plain binary search will dominate as it's bounded better.** However, assuming that it is 'well distributed random data', then the approach with the linear probe could hone in on a very small linear scan set (smaller C for final loops).

This is similar to why a linear scan is *faster for small arrays*, and why a merge-sort or quick-sort (eg.) may switch to an insertion sort for near-leaf sorting. Big-O describes the behavior as n -> Inifinity, without consideration of the constant costs.

<sup>1</sup>The scan could also be `midpoint=n/2..start=0`.. in that case the degenerate case shown is the ideal case and corresponding degenerate case would be `[0, 1, 1, 1 ...]`.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the worst case of the binary search will still be way better (for large values of n) than the worst case of the linear hybrid

Comment: That is correct. The worst-case of the pure binary search is limited. Of course, *the hybrid could be adjusted to avoid this worst-case*: ie. only switch to the scan when `middle - start` < 20 (assuming that a linear scan over ~20 elements has a lower real-world cost than a binary search in the same range). Then both would be bounded equivalently with the hybrid allowing faster near-leaf scans.

Comment: Can we say something about the average case?